# Get a sum , the result with decimals

Tags: symfony, twig

I have two variables in twig, total and pagos,these , store numbers with decimals , the problem is that when the rest , it returns me only the integer part.
Example:

```
{% set total = (proyecto.precioNormal) | number_format(2, '.', ',') %}
{% set pagos = (proyecto.precioPago) | number_format(2, '.', ',') %}
<h2>{{ (total - pagos) | number_format(2, '.', ',') }}</h2>
```

Result:
if total = 5,660.46 and pagos = 0, result is = 5,00

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're subtracting two strings, which won't give you any sort of [sensible numeric result](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/56a32f21b6228e96ae2b9b3b787993452cbd4eaa).

```
php -r 'echo "5,660.46" - "0.00";'
> 5
```

You need to `number_format` the result, **not the values**:

```
{% set total = proyecto.precioNormal %}
{% set pagos = proyecto.precioPago %}
<h2>{{ (total - pagos) | number_format(2, '.', ',') }}</h2>
```

Comment: hello, thanks for your answer , when I make your solution , the result is 5,00, I go to update my question

Comment: @IvanJavierBarrancoGavilan Your updated question is still using formatted strings for `total` and `pagos`. You need to use the PHP numeric values.

Comment: @IvanJavierBarrancoGavilan You're welcome! Once the required 15 minutes have elapsed, make sure to accept the answer that you found most helpful by clicking the grey checkmark next to your desired answer below the up/down arrows.